# SQL Oracle 19 Как объединить часть данных в группировке GROUP BY

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

Хочу, чтоб выдало 3 строки в группировке:
Иван
Петр
Другие
Вот как объединить все другие варианты (Ольга, Юлия) в одно ?

```
Имя Зарплата
Иван    2000
Ольга   3000
Иван    4000
Петр    5000
Юлия    6000
Петр    7000
Иван    8000
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Используйте `CASE - WHEN` в `SELECT` и `GROUP BY`:

```sql
-- MyTable(Name, Salary)

SELECT 
    CASE WHEN Name IN('Петр', 'Иван') THEN Name ELSE 'Другие' END AS Name, 
    SUM(Salary) AS TotSalary
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY (CASE WHEN Name IN('Петр', 'Иван') THEN Name ELSE 'Другие' END)
```

Или же во вложенном запросе (inline view):

```sql
-- MyTable(Name, Salary)

SELECT Name, SUM(Salary)
FROM (
    SELECT 
        CASE WHEN Name IN('Петр', 'Иван') THEN Name ELSE 'Другие' END AS Name, 
        Salary
        FROM MyTable
) MyView
GROUP BY Name
```

Answer (score 1):

```
with t as (
    SELECT 
        CASE
            WHEN name IN ('Петр', 'Иван') THEN name
            ELSE 'Другие'
        END AS name, 
        salary
    FROM mytable
)
SELECT name, SUM(salary) from t GROUP BY name;
```